# Homotopy of $f\in C(S^1)$ to $z^n$.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, differential-topology, homotopy-theory

Reading this paper http://faculty.tcu.edu/richardson/Seminars/EftonToeplitz_2016.pdf and trying to understand the Toeplitz operator's index i have found on page 4 such statement:
Every nonvanishing function on $C(S^1)$ can be homotoped to $z^n$
for some $n$. I suppose that the topology on $C(S^1)$ is generated by the supremum norm. Intuitivly i understand that it's correct statement, but I can't proof this statement strick, i clearly don't understand how to find such $n$ and how to construct such homotopy, any help will be very usefull, thanks.

Comment: Given your $f\in C(S^1)$,  consider the function
  $$
  F:t\in [0, 2\pi ]\mapsto f(e^{it})\in {\mathbb C},
  $$
  and try to find a continuous function
  $$
  G:[0, 2\pi ]\to {\mathbb C},
  $$
  such that
  $$
  F(t) = e^{G(t)}.
  $$

Comment: By $C(S^1)$ you mean continuous maps $S^1\to S^1$?

Comment: No, continuous maps $S^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$